# Strategy for [lazy-]loading Core Data properties asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, core-data, asynchronous, properties, transient

Let's say that you're modelling take-out restaurants in Core Data. Each `Restaurant` should have a `phoneNumber` property, but it will be different depending on the user's street address. Have no fear, though, there's a REST API that helps you to convert street addresses and restaurant IDs to phone numbers.

I would like to model the `phoneNumber` property of `Restaurants` such that the REST API is contacted:

1. only as needed (ie. when the `phoneNumber` property is accessed)
2. as infrequently as possible

The strategy I'm considering goes something like this:

1. offer a KVO-compliant `phoneNumberLoaded` boolean on restaurants
2. return `nil` when accessing `phoneNumber` in an unloaded state
3. start to asynchronously load the `phoneNumber` property either:

   1. the first time it's accessed
   2. when the user calls a `preloadPhoneNumber` method
4. maintain a queue that receives preload requests on behalf of the API, batching them up
5. update the `phoneNumber` as the API calls return, setting `phoneNumberLoaded` to `YES`

Shall I get to work, or does anyone have a better strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you meant but this is how I see it:

Restaurant<<-->Address (city,street,needPhoneResolutoin[BOOL],phoneNumber[default value: nil])
Create a class that will handle resolution (PhoneResolver).
The resolver will have a FRC with entity: `Address`, predicate: `needPhoneResolution == YES AND phoneNumber == nil`.
implement the delegate methods, but handle only inserted objects (and all objects that exist after the first perform fetch call) and deleted objects (cleanup).
batch them up (at `-controllerDidChangeContent:`)
perform the REST fetch
update the DB.
report failure to resolver (another fetch will be needed, or mark the address as unresolvable).

This way, you don't need to implement yourself the queue or the KVO (provided by CoreData), and by principle of locality, if a user requested the phone once (and the fetch failed), you would still keep the user request for that phone and try to fetch it every time the resolver is started.